# Roles based api call --using azure ad access token or id token?

Tags: azure-active-directory, authorization, azure-ad-msal, bearer-token

I have an angular application which communicates with a backend REST API(java spring boot). This REST API is made specifically to serve the SPA. In order to navigate or use any functionality of the SPA beyond the home page, users must log in first.

The thing is the access of API call is based on the role. In azure we added mapped claims to the ID token so we can get the employee ID. We use msal to get tokens. Now we need to pass the token in angular interceptor.

```
const headers = request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${result.idToken}`);
```

The application is working but I am not confident about this. Am I wrong? Should I use access token instead? If I replace the id token with access token such as

```
 const headers = request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${result.accessToken}`);
```

then I get 401 error from the back end.

Comment: Seems it consider to be more secure to call a  Rest WebAPI using access token  : https://code-maze.com/secure-angular-calls-to-webapi-using-access-token/

Comment: Bearer Authentication Scheme was initially created as part of OAuth 2.0 and access token is issued by auth server as part of OAuth2.0  flow . So if you pass like this **Bearer ${result.idToken}** with ID token it will throw wrong authrozation header error or contains an invalid bearer token and the server may respond with a 401 (Unauthorized) status code

Comment: ID token is only assume for user is authenticate not to call an API for more information you can read this blog for difference btwn ID token and Access token : https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference/

Answer (score 0):

Id Token comes from `OpenID` connect and Access Token comes from `Oauth2.0`.

Bearer Authentication Scheme was initially created as part of OAuth 2.0 and access token is issued by auth server as part of OAuth2.0 flow. So if you pass like this **Bearer ${result.idToken}** with ID token it will throw wrong authorization header error or contains an invalid bearer token and the server may respond with a 401 (Unauthorized) status code.

ID token is only use for to know the user is authenticate and get the user profile data. So, ID token not suitable for call an API.

Access token is use for accessing the resources and check If client is allowed to access for something or not.

For more information why the ID token is not secure to call an API you can refer this [blog](https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference/)

Comment: Thanks for your input. But the thing is I passed `Bearer ${result.idToken}` with ID token then it is good. If I pass  `Bearer ${result.accessToken}`  then throw 401 error.